# Flink Avro Serialization shows "not serializable" error when working with GenericRecords

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm really having a hard time making Flink to communicate properly with a running Kafka instance making use of an Avro schema from the Confluent Schema Registry (for **both** key and value).

After a while of thinking and restructuring my programm, I was able to push my implementation so far:

**Producer Method**

```
    public static FlinkKafkaProducer<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>> kafkaAvroGenericProducer() {  
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "--.-.-.--:9092");
        properties.put("schema.registry.url", "http://--.-.-.---:8081");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KVSerializationSchema.class.getName()); //wrong class should not matter
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KVSerializationSchema.class.getName()); //wrong class but should not matter


        return new FlinkKafkaProducer<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>("flink_output",
                new GenericSerializer("flink_output", schemaK, schemaV, "http://--.-.-.---:8081"),
                properties, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);

    }
```

---

**GenericSerializer.java**

```
package com.reeeliance.flink;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.KafkaSerializationSchema;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import flinkfix.ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema;

public class GenericSerializer implements KafkaSerializationSchema<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>{

    private String topic;   
    private Schema schemaKey;
    private Schema schemaValue;
    private String registryUrl;

    public GenericSerializer(String topic, Schema schemaK, Schema schemaV, String url) {
        super();
        this.topic = topic;
        this.schemaKey = schemaK;
        this.schemaValue = schemaV;
        this.registryUrl = url;
    }

    public GenericSerializer() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord> element, Long timestamp) {
        byte[] key = ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(topic + "-key", schemaKey, registryUrl).serialize(element.f0);
        byte[] value = ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(topic + "-value", schemaValue, registryUrl).serialize(element.f1);

        return new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic, key, value);
    }

}
```

---

However, when I execute the Job, it fails in the preparation phase, without the Job actually running with following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: [H_EQUNR type:STRING pos:0] is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:151)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:71)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:617)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:571)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.<init>(FlinkKafkaProducer.java:547)
    at com.reeeliance.flink.StreamingJob.kafkaAvroGenericProducer(StreamingJob.java:257)
    at com.reeeliance.flink.StreamingJob.main(StreamingJob.java:84)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field
    - custom writeObject data (class "java.util.ArrayList")
    - root object (class "org.apache.avro.Schema$LockableArrayList", [H_EQUNR type:STRING pos:0])
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1182)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner.clean(ClosureCleaner.java:133)
    ... 8 more
```

---

I know all classes have to implement *Serializable*-Interface or to be made transient, but I don't use my own classes and the error does not address a function, which is not serializable (as usual threads deal with), but rather a record or field.
The field comes from the key schema, a schema containing only this one field. I assume my error lies somewhere in using GenericRecord, which does not implement *Serializable*-Interface, but I see GenericRecord being used for this kind of Serialization a lot, so it doesn't really make sense to me.

The class *ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema* is taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/flink/commit/37a818ce8714adf14153587bf99c0900e5af42b7), as it is not yet included in the current Flink version (1.9.1) we are using. I included the necessary classes and changed classes and I don't think this might be the reason for my problem. ([Issue solved](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9679))

Can anybody help me debug this? I would also appreciate a lot, if you could show me a different way to achieve the same goal, the incompatibility of Flink Avro and Confluent Schema Registry has been driving me crazy so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception message tells you which class is not serializable.

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$Field
```

The problem lies in the `Schema` class which you store in the fields of you `GenericSerializer`.

You could try this:

```
public class GenericSerializer implements KafkaSerializationSchema<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>{

    private final SerializationSchema<GenericRecord> valueDeserializer;
    private final SerializationSchema<GenericRecord> keyDeserializer;

    public GenericSerializer(String topic, Schema schemaK, Schema schemaV, String url) {
        this.keyDeserializer = ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(topic + "-key", schemaKey, registryUrl);
        this.valueDeserializer = ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(topic + "-value", schemaValue, registryUrl); 
    }

    @Override
    public ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord> element, Long timestamp) {
        byte[] key = keySerializer.serialize(element.f0);
        byte[] value = valueSerializer.serialize(element.f1);

        return new ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>(topic, key, value);
    }

}
```

The `ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema` is serializable therefore you can safely store it in a field in your `GenericSerializer`.

It will also be more performant as the underlying structures will not be reinstantiated for every incoming record.

Comment: I already identified Schema$Field as the culprit, yet I just couldn't wrap my head around *where* it may possibly cause problems. I tried moving the parsing of the schema to another point in the application, to only include strings in my constructor, but I was not aware of the fact that the existence of fields with Type *Schema* would be my problem. Thanks a lot, it was a great answer and I immediately understood where my fault was. I'm running into different issues now but this helped a lot

Comment: You wouldnt by any chance know, why ```Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.avro.JsonProperties$2.putIfAbsent(JsonProperties.java:159)
 [...]com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:144)
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:21)
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:679)
 at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
 ... 27 more``` would occur? Unfortunately I cannot disable Kryo fallback, since I am using GenericRecords

Comment: Kryo serializer will not work for `GenericRecords`. GenericRecords are not JavaSerializable nor KryoSerializable. You can try using the `new AvroSerializer(GenericRecord.class, Schema(...))` with your state.

Comment: What do you mean by "with your state"? I already have written a Serializer class, or do you mean I have to register it?

Comment: Exceptions from KryoSerializers mean that you are using GenricTypeInformation somewhere. Either when serializing between operators or when storing it in state (e.g. ListState, MapState, ValueState etc.). Kryo cannot serialize GenericRecord.

Comment: But I don't even want Kryo to do anything, I thought that's the point of doing a manual transformation to byte arrays. In my case, where I have custom Ser/Des, what do I need Kryo for and how/where is it invoked? The documentation deals only briefly with Kryo.
I got a Deserializer which includes this, but that's the only occurance of any TypeInformation in the whole project:
```@Override
    public TypeInformation<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<GenericRecord,GenericRecord>>() {});
    }```

Comment: That's exactly the place where you say to use the `KryoSerializer`. You are running a type extraction process via call to `TypeInformation.of()` which does not understand the `GenericRecord` and fallbacks to Kryo. Try using `new TupleTypeInfo(new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(...), new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(...))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206932/discussion-between-kopaka-and-dawid-wysakowicz).

Answer (score 0):

was there any conclusion about the issue that Flink is falling back to kryo for avro generic record?

I'm using scala and added the typeinformation like this:

```
implicit val typeInformation: TypeInformation[GenericRecord] = TypeInformation.of( new TypeHint[GenericRecord] {
      new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(EventMessage.SCHEMA$)
    })
```

The stream is setup like this:

```
DataStream[GenericRecord]
```

But Flink Runtime still falls back to kryo because it cannot recognise the Avro Generic Record and treats it as any generic type.

Comment: As far as I remember, Flink has problems with typing `GenericRecord`, but not with typing `Tuple`, so switching the Type to `Tuple1<GenericRecord>` should definitely work. In your case, changing `TypeInformation.of()` to `new TupleTypeInfo<Tuple1<GenericRecord>>(new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaString)))` would make this work. I couldn't make `GenericRecord` work without wrapping it, but it may still be possible.

Comment: I changed it to  
```implicit val typeInformation: TypeInformation[Tuple1[GenericRecord]] = TypeInformation.of(
      new TupleTypeInfo[Tuple1[GenericRecord]](new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(
        EventMessage.SCHEMA$
      ))
    )```


But the compiler complains about it and underlines `.of() ` in the `TypeInformation.of()` call. Saying it can't get overloaded...

Comment: In Java, `TupleTypeInfo` is a subclass of `TypeInformation` and thus, can be used directly without the `TypeInformation.of()` part. I think it should be similar in Scala

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the org.apache.avro.Schema$Field class. The class is not serializable which is resulting in this exception. The solution is mentioned in the flink documentation as well under the note section

`Since Avro’s Schema class is not serializable, it can not be sent around as is. You can work around this by converting it to a String and parsing it back when needed. If you only do this once on initialization, there is practically no difference to sending it directly.`

so we need to make the parsing with each message we are getting, we can't do it only once in constructor, it will be same as passing into the constructor itself.

So the solution can be like the following snippet. We will be accepting the avro schema as string in constructor and will be creating avro schema in the serialize method.

```html
class AvroMessageSerializationSchema(topic: String, schemaString: String, schemaRegistry: String) extends KafkaSerializationSchema[GenericRecord] {

  private def getSchema(schema: String): Schema = {
    new Schema.Parser().parse(schema)
  }

  override def serialize(element: GenericRecord, timestamp: lang.Long): ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = {
    val schema = getSchema(schemaString)
    val value = ConfluentRegistryAvroSerializationSchema.forGeneric(topic, schema, schemaRegistry).serialize(element)
    new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]](topic, value)
  }
}
```

One more thing, we need to keep in mind is to provide typeInformation which the flink will require to serialize avro else it will fallback to kyro for serialization.

```
implicit val typeInformation: TypeInformation[GenericRecord] = new GenericRecordAvroTypeInfo(avroSchema)
```

[avro serialization with flink](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/04/15/flink-serialization-tuning-vol-1.html#avro)